# I want to have heading of TOC not in bold font

Tags: table-of-contents

I tried:

```
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{{\Huge\contentsname}}
\tableofcontents
```

but result was: only `ToC` heading (well formatting :-), and no `ToC` :-(!

I have:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your redefinition of `\tableofcontents` is really wrong! Please provide a compilable document, not just fragments

Comment: Are you referring to your chapter entries being **bold** still? And you don't want that?

Comment: I want to have my chapter entries not in bold font, I think it is too strong and "dark".

Answer (score 1):

Using `\cfttoctitlefont` from `tocloft` it is possible to change the font style of the `ToC` heading very easily.

Of course,

```
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{{\Huge\contentsname}}
\tableofcontents
```

is completely wrong, since this does just print the `\contentsname` in `\Huge` font and the functionality of `\tableofcontents` is corrupted (since it does not use `\@starttoc` anymore.)

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\Huge}

\begin{document}


\tableofcontents

\chapter{Foo}
\section{Foo section}
\subsection{Foo subsection}

\chapter{Foobar}
\section{Foobar section}
\subsection{Foobar subsection}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thank you very much. It is perfect and not difficult.

Comment: I am a greenhorn here, I don't understand your sentence: "Please consider to accept this answer then." Vielleicht soll ich etwas schreiben, aber ich weiss nicht wohin. Nochmal danke ich fuer gute Hilfe.

Comment: Hier ist es beschrieben: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer -- Häkchen setzen ;-)